# How to use box-sizing: border-box with 2 inline elements?

Tags: css, border-box

I am trying to mantain 2 elements inline maintaining the width of 100% with borders and paddings, I tried to use box-sizing but are not working. What is wrong? HTML:

```
<div class="content">
<aside class="left-nav">
<h2>Menu</h2>
</aside>
<section class="section-main">Test</section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-top: 82px;
height: 1000px;
border: solid 2px green;
}
.left-nav {
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline-block;
width: 20%;
border: 1px solid red;
}
.section-main {
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline-block;
width: 80%;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/W7EJB/

Answer (score 3):

It's a problem with **inline-block** element.Give **font-size:0;** to the parent element. Write like this:

```
.content {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 82px;
    height: 1000px;
    border: solid 2px green;
    font-size:0;
}
.left-nav {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-size:16px;
}
.section-main {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/W7EJB/1/

Comment: you are not coded wrong. But it's good if you write like this http://jsfiddle.net/W7EJB/2/

Comment: Yeeess, this works for me. Is it cross-browser solution?